# Modification of innerHTML stored in variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to store the display area of a page in a variable (`display` in the code), i.e. the innerHTML of the `display` div in my example, but when I do that I cannot modify its content at all.

```js
function stored() {
  var display = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
  display = "Bonjour";
}

function notStored() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stored()">Stored in variable</button>
<button onclick="notStored()">Not stored in variable</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `innerHTML` of an element is a string, the reference to the element is not preserved, when you read that string to a variable.

Comment: You can't affect references to variables. What you are doing in your furst block is copying the innerHTML of your element.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you. Is it only the case for strings? I find it strange because this is not the case in Java.

Comment: Yes, all primitives act the same way. I suppose they do in Java too ...

Comment: @Teemu Strings are not primitives in Java. But is there a system of references for objects in Js?

Comment: Yep, objects are seemingly passed by reference (actually they are also passed by value, but the passed value is a copy of a reference). You could pull `display` declaration out of the `stored` function, and then set `display.innerHTML = ....` in the functions. That way `display` would contain the reference to the HTML element. That's what I think you actually need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you assigned a new value to your `display` variable. What you want to do is to set the `innerHTML` of `display` to a variable, eg `stored`. By doing that, you stored your desired `innerHTML` as a variable.

```js
function stored() {
  var stored = "Bonjour";
  var display = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = stored;
}

function notStored() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stored()">Stored in variable</button>
<button onclick="notStored()">Not stored in variable</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: That's all the polysemy of `=` for strings. Does it mean assign a reference to the variable, or affect a value to the string? I think that's the main reason why they made strings immutable.

Answer (score 2):

The innerHTML attribute is a simple String, therefore it's immutable, moreover, you're only assigning a value to a variable rather than updating the current HTML content.

You need to assign the new value to the attribute `innerHTML`:

```js
function stored() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Bonjour";
}

function notStored() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stored()">Stored in variable</button>
<button onclick="notStored()">Not stored in variable</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Oh you're right, strings are immutable. But if it was a mutable object, would I be able to store it on a variable? Is there a system of references in Javascript like in Java?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi you can store it in a variable (what you can't do is modify it), the references in JS are similar to Java, every variable is a pointer to a value in memory.

Comment: Unless primitive types I presume, and Strings are not primitives in Java.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi yes, you're right.  [Primitive in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)