# Why is my DOM manipulation not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to replace the list of paragraphs with only one random paragraph, but for some reason the JavaScript code will not do the job.

I have tried rearranging the variables after the function has ended, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

This is how my HTML elements begin:

```
<body>
  <div id = "quotes">
    <p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable for us.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Everything which distinguishes man from the animals depends upon this ability to volatilize perceptual metaphors in a schema, and thus to dissolve an image into a concept.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Our destiny exercises its influence over us even when, as yet, we have not learned its nature: it is our future that lays down the law of our today.&#8221;</p>
```

And this is my attempt at DOM manipulation:

```
"use strict";
const quotes = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const randomize = function() {
  let num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(quotes.length)) - 1);
  let quote = quotes.item(num).innerHTML;
return quote;
}
let randomQuote = randomize();
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML;
passage = randomQuote;
console.log(randomQuote);
```

Comment: You need to assign `randomQuote` directly to `innerHTML` to set it. `passage = randomQuote;` just changes the value of the variable which doesn’t change the DOM at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modification of innerHTML stored in variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878217/modification-of-innerhtml-stored-in-variable-not-working)

Comment: You are generating one random paragraph in the console. Is this not what you want to do? Your problem is that your equation for getting num is not correct and sometimes results in getting a number that throws an error.

Comment: @ecg8 read the answers (and his question), although his num equation is incorrect OP was also attempting to alter the DOM unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the HTML of a node (with `innerHTML`) is to *assign* to its `innerHTML` property, which invokes an internal setter operation. Extracting the `innerHTML` of a node into a variable and then reassigning that variable won't do anything. (reassigning a variable reference to something else won't ever change anything, by itself.)

So, use

```
document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML = randomQuote;
```

You also need to fix your `num` random number generator - use `Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);` to generate a number between 0 and `quotes.length - 1`, otherwise `num` will sometimes be `-1` (whose index doesn't exist, of course):

```js
"use strict";
const quotes = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const randomize = function() {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  return quotes.item(num).innerHTML;
}
const randomQuote = randomize();
document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML = randomQuote;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="quotes">
    <p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable
      for us.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Everything which distinguishes man from the animals depends upon this ability to volatilize perceptual metaphors in a schema, and thus to dissolve an image into a concept.&#8221;</p>
    <p>&#8220;Our destiny exercises its influence over us even when, as yet, we have not learned its nature: it is our future that lays down the law of our today.&#8221;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that

```
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML;
```

Sets the value of passage to the instantaneous value of the innerHTML of quotes, it is not a reference (which is not possible in javascript btw).

```
passage = randomQuote;
```

Just overwrites the value of passage with the random quote. Instead you should write

```
document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML = randomQuote;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML;
passage = randomQuote;
```

You should do:

```
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes');
passage.innerHTML = randomQuote;
```

**Why**

In this line:

```
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML;
```

You are actually getting the reference of a string from `.innerHTML` to `passage`, not the element itself.

Therefore, in the next line:

```
passage = randomQuote;
```

You are only replacing the string with a another string, instead of replacing the property value of an element. Because `passage` is not an element, it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your example instead of assigning new quote to the innerHtml, you just change the variable with value for it that doesn't keep reference to the innerHtml anymore, just it's value

Just change this:

```
let passage = document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML= randomQuote;
```